# getting difference and eliminating gap time series data using pandas and numpy

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, time-series

I'm a beginner of Python related environment and I have problem with using time series data.

The below is my Close 1 minute data of every day.

```
    2011-11-01, 248.70, 248.85, 249.15, ... 250.15, 250.60, 250.55
    2011-11-02, 245.80, 246.35, 245.80, ...
    ...
```

1. I'd like to change time series values based on 'last close value of yesterday' like the following:

   ```
   2011-11-01, (248.70 - 248.70), (248.85 - 248.70), (249.15 - 248.70), ... 250.15 - 248.70, 250.60 - 248.70, 250.55 - 248.70
   2011-11-02, (245.80 - 250.55), (246.35 - 250.55), (245.80 - 250.55), ...
   ...
   ```

At the first line of the above example, 248.70 (which is the 'today's open' value) is used as subtraction element, because it's impossible to get 'yesterday's close' value.

1. I'd like to eliminate GAP between yesterday and today:

   ```
   2011-11-01, 248.70, 248.85, 249.15, ... 250.15, 250.60, 250.55
   2011-11-02, 245.80 - (245.80 - 250.55), 246.35 - (245.80 - 250.55), 245.80 - (245.80 - 250.55), ...
   ...
   ```

Any help would be very appreciated.

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume you've loaded these comma-separated values into a DataFrame indexed by date with a column for each minute. The final column will be the last close value. Something like:

```
df = read_csv('filename.csv', header=None, index_col=0, parse_dates=0)
```

To compare today's values to yesterday's last value, take the last column and use shift to look "up" one row.

```
last_column = df.columns[-1]
df1 = df - df[last_column].shift(1) # last close value of yesterday
```

The second part of your question follows similarly:

```
first_column = df.columns[0]
df2 = df - (df[first_column] - df[last_column].shift(1))
```